# Problem with deleting a desired element of the linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I came upon a problem in which i can not delete a element of a linked list with a given position. I need to delete a element with a uneven value (my list are numbers form 1 to 100 included).

Here are my two functions:

```
void Delete_Node(Queue *queue, int position)
{
    Node *oldNode;
    Node *NEXT;
    Node *prev;
    int i;
    
    int deleted_number;
    
    if (position == 1)
    {
        oldNode = queue->head;
        deleted_number = queue->head->value;
        
        queue->head = queue->head->next;
        
        free(oldNode); 
        
        queue->size--;  
    }
    else
    {
        prev = queue->head;
        
        for (i = 1; i < position - 1; i++)
            prev = prev->next;
        
        oldNode = prev->next;
        NEXT = prev->next->next;
        
        oldNode = NULL;
        
        prev->next = NEXT;
        
        queue->size--;  
        
    }
    printf("\nDeleted: %d", deleted_number);
}

void DeleteUneven(Queue *queue)
{
    int pos = 1;
    Node *temp;
    temp = queue->head;
    
    while (1)
    {
        if (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (pos == 1)
            {
                if (temp->value % 2 == 1)
                {
                    Delete_Node(queue, pos);
                    temp = queue->head;
                    pos--;
                }
                else
                    temp = temp->next;
                
                pos++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (temp->value % 2 == 1)
                {
                    Delete_Node(queue, pos);
                    pos--;
                }
                else
                    temp = temp->next;
                
                pos++;  
            }
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

The output after using function

```
DeleteUneven(list_of_numbers_form_1_to_100);
```

is

```
Deleted 1
Deleted 1
Deleted 1
...
```

I think the problem is in function `Delete_Node` when I tried to make a `temp->next` to be a `temp->next->next`. But I dont know... I am still learning and this concept is new to me.

Comment: There is no 'main' function: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Instead of live-coding here, prepare a [mre] offline and present it when you are done.

Comment: There are several problems with your code: Your "temp" becomes invalid after the call to Delete_Node, but you continue to use it after that. Also the code is extremely inefficient, because Delete_Node takes a position as argument - it should instead use the Queue pointer directly. There is no need to keep track of the position at all!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in the `DeleteUneven()` function. When `pos != 1` and the odd  numbered node is  deleted, the code needs to move on to the next node (`temp->next`)in the queue for continuing the next iteration of  while loop. You are handling the the movement to the next node for the else part of the `pos != 1` condition when the even numbered node is not being deleted.

Recommended change:

```
if (temp!=NULL)
        {
            if(pos == 1)
            {
                if(temp->value%2==1)
                {
                    Delete_Node(queue,pos);
                    temp = queue->head;
                    pos--;
                }
                else
                    temp = temp->next;
                pos++;

            }
            else
            {
                if(temp->value%2 == 1)
                {
                    temp=temp->next; //save the next node's adress before deleting current node
                    Delete_Node(queue,pos);
                    pos--;

                }
                else
                    temp = temp->next;
                pos++;
            }
        }
```

The other issue is in the `Delete_Node()` function. Set the number `deleted_number` of the node also in the case where it is not a head node (`queue-> head`), so that it can be printed later. Also free the memory of the deleted node (`oldNode`)for this case:

```
    if (position == 1)
    {
        oldNode = queue->head;
        deleted_number = queue->head->value;
        queue->head = queue->head->next;
    }
    else
    {
        prev = queue->head;
        for (i = 1 ; i < position - 1 ; i++) {
            prev = prev->next;
        }
        deleted_number=prev->next->value; 
        oldNode = prev->next;
        NEXT = prev->next->next;    
        prev->next = NEXT;
    }
    free (oldNode); 
    queue->size--;
    printf("\nDeleted: %d qsz=%d",deleted_number, queue->size);
```